# Akka HTTP multiple file upload to S3

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm working on developing an API to upload multiple files to S3 with Akka HTTP. I'm currently using the [`fileUploadAll`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/fileUploadAll.html) directive, which buffers all the files to disk. This is putting a limitation on the size of files that can be handled. Are there alternate approaches? How else can I handle multipart/form-data requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example that takes a list of file paths, converts the list to a single `Source[ByteString, _]`, and runs the `Source` with an [Alpakka S3 connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.17/s3.html#storing-a-file-in-s3) `Sink` that uploads the data to S3:

```
val paths = List(Paths.get("/path/to/file1"), Paths.get("/path/to/file2"))
val source: Source[ByteString, _] = Source(paths).flatMapConcat(FileIO.fromPath(_))

// read the Alpakka documentation about setting up a S3 client and sink
val s3Sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = ???

val fut: Future[MultipartUploadResult] = source.runWith(s3Sink)
```

You could use `fut` with one of the [future directives](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.0/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/index.html) in your Akka HTTP route.

---

As mentioned, the above approach creates a single `Source`. If you need distinct buckets and keys for each file, then you could launch separate streams for each file:

```
val source1: Source[ByteString, _] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/path/to/file1"))
val source2: Source[ByteString, _] = FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("/path/to/file2")

val s3Sink1: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = ???
val s3Sink2: Sink[ByteString, Future[MultipartUploadResult]] = ???

val fut1: Future[MultipartUploadResult] = source1.runWith(s3Sink1)
val fut2: Future[MultipartUploadResult] = source2.runWith(s3Sink2)

val fut: Future[List[MultipartUploadResult]] = Future.sequence(List(fut1, fut2))
```